# API call occurs duplicate contents

Tags: api, vue.js

I use VueJS for a project and Axios for API call. I don't know how to execute this code once. When I go in my home page this code is executed, I go to another page, I go back and this code is executed again. How to cancel execution ?

```
mounted () {

    axios

      .get( config.API.projects )
        .then(response => {

          this.SET_PROJECTS( response.data ); 

          const projects = this.$store.getters["projects/projects"];

          projects.forEach( project => {
            this.SET_SKILLS( project.skills )
          });

          this.SET_SHOW_LOADER( false );

        })
        .catch( ( error ) => {
          console.log( error );
          alert( "Une erreur est survenue, merci de contacter par mail l'administrateur de ce site" )
        });

  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Your VUEX getter `"projects/projects"` is an array, and is not populated before the call, you can just do a check to see if it has any data. If it is empty (`length equal to zero`) you want to get the data and populate it with it. Next time you enter this view, the check will fail, since the store is already populated with the results. (`length of projects is greater than 0`)

```js
mounted () {

  const projects = this.$store.getters["projects/projects"];

  if (projects.length === 0) {
    axios.get( config.API.projects ).then(response => {

      this.SET_PROJECTS( response.data ); 

      projects.forEach( project => {
        this.SET_SKILLS( project.skills )
      });

      this.SET_SHOW_LOADER( false );

    })
    .catch( ( error ) => {
      console.log( error );
      alert( "Une erreur est survenue, merci de contacter par mail l'administrateur de ce site" )
    });
  }

},
```

**Bonus tip:** Be carefull with using `.catch`. I assume you want to "catch" only if there is any errors with getting the data with axios. What you are also doing, it actually catching/silencing every error from the line `axios.get(...` to the line `.catch`. This means that if let's say you get an error inside the `.then` function, eg: `"SET_PROJECTS" is not an function` and your app breaks, **you will not get it in the console**

In your case, you will. But only because you `console.log` the error parameter from the `.catch`. If you did not do this, you would never know there was any errors.

To fix this, simply change `.catch` to the 2nd parameter of the `.then` function:

```js
if (projects.length === 0) {
    axios.get( config.API.projects ).then(response => {

      this.SET_PROJECTS( response.data ); 

      projects.forEach( project => {
        this.SET_SKILLS( project.skills )
      });

      this.SET_SHOW_LOADER( false );

    }, error => {
      console.log( error );
      alert( "Une erreur est survenue, merci de contacter par mail l'administrateur de ce site" )
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot that was very helpful I'm going to try your tips :)

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark the question as answered. If not, please keep me updated on what is not working :D

Comment: I'm glad it does! Have a nice day, my dude.